# html input pattern to accept only numbers from 4-10 and the char M

Tags: html

The title says it all.

How can I make an input accept only numbers from 4-10 and the letter M and nothing else?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HTML5 validation. The [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern) attribute lets you specify a regular expression the value of the input must match:

```html
<input pattern="[4-9]|10|M"
       title="Enter a number between ‘4’ and ‘10’, or the character ‘M’" 
/>
```

Comment: Is pattern case insensitive by default?

Comment: @h7r No, it should be case sensitive. Didn't think about that, probably I should have used `M` or `m|M`.

Comment: Then the input should be `<input pattern="[4-9]|10|M" />`

Answer (score 1):

Question already answered, follow the link, the answer there has HTML 5, JavaScript, JQuery, and more solutions.
But as the answer states, don't forget to do a server side solution, because the JavaScript might be trespassed or deactivated, and the HTML5 might not work in old browsers. Don't trust user input, re-verify in server side.
[HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)